# How to do integration test for web client?

Tags: spring-webflux, webclient, webtestclient

I have a method which returns Mono. So I try to user step verifier to do a integrate test.

```
public Mono<Void> process(InputBody body)  {

  retrun webClient
        .post()
        .uri("/submit")
        .body(Mono.just(body), InputBody .class)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Void.class)
        .subscribe()      
}
```

I want to do a integrate test for this.

my question is, when we use Web Client Test how to return mono void and step verify it?

```
 webClient
        .post()
        .uri("/submit")
        .body(Mono.just(body), InputBody .class)
        .exchange()
      .........
```

how to complete things? I tried but failed.

Comment: first of all dont subscribe. Your service is a producer, and the calling client is the subscriber. Also subscribe does not return a mono, it returns a `Disposable` which is very different https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe-- so you can start there by removing the subscribe. Also i see no stepverifier in your code and also update your code with your full test class and function.

Comment: @Toerktumlare , That is what I have no idea to code on step verifier if it return Mono<Void>.